# one method for different classes StringBuilder and StringBuffer

Tags: java

I have two methods for each class (StringBuffer and StringBuilder) with duplicated code

```
 public  void myStringBuffer() {
 StringBuffer sBuf=new StringBuffer("stringBuffer");
  //some code
 }

 public  void myStringBuilder() {
 StringBuilder sBuil=new StringBuilder("stringBuilder");
  //some code (same as in first method, duplicated)
 }
```

I want to extract this code in method , but I have different Classes

```
public someCode( Class<T> myStringObject)
```

It's about Generics, but how?

UPD: YES, there is nothing with Generics ))
Thanks for answers.

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics. You'd need to use `Object` and the code would be really ugly. Why do you want this?

Comment: What does _some code_ mean? Are you calling methods of a common super type? That's the only thing that generics can do for you.

Comment: @Pillar you don't need generics to call methods of a common supertype, just a reference of the common supertype.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sure.

Comment: Unrelated but why Javadoc does not show that `StringBuffer` implements `Appendable`: `public final class StringBuffer extends Object implements Serializable, CharSequence`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: @tsolakp it does in the "All implemented interfaces" section

Comment: @Sirmyself. But it should also do in class definition part of Javadoc like it does not `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both implement `Appendable`, so just pull out your common code into a method:

```
 public  void myStringBuffer() {
   common(new StringBuffer("stringBuffer"));
 }

 public  void myStringBuilder() {
   common(new StringBuilder("stringBuffer"));
 }

 private void common(Appendable appendable) {
   // some code.
 }
```

Should you need methods from other implemented interfaces, use an intersection type:

```
<T extends CharSequence & Appendable> void common(T t) {
  // Some code.
}
```

Comment: davidxxx 's answer would have been a better one since this one does not allow the use of methods implemented by the other interfaces of `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 2):

Define a method specifying as parameter a variable with a type allowing to invoke the required methods of these two classes. 
`AbstractStringBuilder` that is the direct superclass both of `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` would be a very good candidate but you cannot use it as it is package private.

So as workaround use `Appendable`.
Note that `Appendable` is far from providing the diversity of methods providing by StringBuffer and StringBuilder.
So as a consequence, this solution **may** not be enough.

```
 public void myBuilder(Appendable  builder) {
  //some code
 }
```

And invoke it :

```
 StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer("stringBuffer");
 myBuilder(sBuf);

 StringBuilder sBuil = new StringBuilder("stringBuffer");
 myBuilder(sBuil);
```

Comment: I had a similar answer, but this one is better, I was not aware of the `AbstractStringBuilder` abstract class

Comment: In fact, no it is not a good idea as the class is not visible (package private). I updated

Comment: @Sirmyself I've not only not heard about it, but how could it be a subclass of two classes in Java, let alone either class since `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` are both `final`?

Comment: @powerlord a final class does not prevent it from inheriting from an other class : it prevents other classes to inherit from it (EDIT : my bad, I read "superclass")

Answer (score 0):

If your code uses methods declared in the `Appendable` interface, you may use this declaration :

```
public void yourMethod(Appendable value) {
    //your code
}
```

If you also need methods from the CharSequence interface, you may need an Object parameter. To make sure you get the correct objects, you will have to manually check if they implement correct interfaces :

```
public void yourMethod(Object obj) throws Exception{
    if (!(obj instanceof Appendable)) {
        throw new Exception("Appendable interface not implemented by the received object"); //or a custom exception would be better
    } else if (!(obj instanceof CharSequence)) {
        throw new Exception("CharSequence interface not implemented by the received object");
    } else {
        Appendable app = (Appendable)obj; //use this one to use Appendable methods
        CharSequence chSeq = (CharSequence)obj; //use this one to use CharSequence methods

        //your code

        //e.g.
        app.append(" string to append");
        int totalLength = chSeq.length(); //would return the length of the resulting string
    }
}
```